# Facebook API photo uploading with imagepng

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, photo-upload

I have a quiz application on Facebook. It uploads a photo to user's photos at the end of the quiz.

```
$photo_upload = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                                'source' => '@' . './images/userimg.png',
                                                'message' => $message,
                                                )
                                            );
```

But it is a sample image, the same for everyone. I want to make it personal by writing the user's name on the image. Part of **create-img.php**:

```
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user_id = null; }

$username = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $user_profile['name']);

$text = iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", "Hello ". $username);

...

header('Content-type: image/png') ;

            ImagePNG($image) ;

            ImageDestroy($image) ;

            imagepng($image, "./images/imgs_to_post/sample_userimg.png");

            exit ;
```

It can be included in HTML, works fine, the image shows up with the user's name.

```
<img src="create-img.php" alt="" />
```

But when I try to put create-img.php as source in the API call above, i get an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#1) An unknown error occurred thrown in /home/mmdesign/public_html/.../php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1128
```

**How can I put the result image of imagepng in the API call as source?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try to put create-img.php as source in the API call above, i get an error.

Of course, because that file contains PHP code, not image data. (If you think the PHP code is *parsed* at this point, you’re wrong.)

Write the image to HDD first, and then feed the API the path to that image.